# php session not saving variables

Tags: php, session, request, slim

I am trying to store three request that and then compare them for my college project. Here's the code:

```
$app->map(['GET'],'/dados/{id}/{corrente}/{tensao}/{potencia}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
if(!isset($_SESSION)) { 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['req1'] = FALSE;
    $_SESSION['req2'] = FALSE;
    $_SESSION['req3'] = FALSE;
} 

require_once("db.php");

$req = array();

$id = $request->getAttribute('id');
$c = $request->getAttribute('corrente');
$v = $request->getAttribute('tensao');
$p = $request->getAttribute('potencia');

echo "id: $id, corrente: $c, tensão: $v, potência: $p \n";

array_push($req,$id,$c,$v,$p);

$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO teste_sustek VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
$query->execute([$id,$c,$v,$p]);

if (empty($_SESSION["req1"])){
    //first request
    $_SESSION["req1"] = $req;
    echo "first request \n";
    echo var_dump($_SESSION["req1"]);
} else if (empty($_SESSION["req2"])){
    //second request
    $_SESSION["req2"] = $req;
    echo "second request";
} else if (empty($_SESSION["req3"])){
    //compare them here
    $_SESSION["req3"] = $req;
    session_destroy();

    echo "third and last request";
} });
```

However when I test it via Postman I always get the following output, as if my session wasn't storing my variables:

id: 1, corrente: 2, tensão: 3, potência: 4

first request

array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=>

string(1) "4" }

Comment: edit: I am using the following route: http://sustek/dados/1/2/3/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `session_start();` in your index.php

Comment: Could you explain me why starting the session inside the route doesn't work?

Comment: it's more a case that you need to call `session_start()` before testing `$_SESSION`. However once you have more than one action, it's easier to start the session in a common place.

Comment: @Tesserato when you define route callbacks (which you've put `session_start` in) you're only defining them, they are not actually executed until the router decides which route callback should be executed. So the order of execution might be slightly different than what appears to eyes. That means in your code you're accessing `$_SESSION` before calling `sesssion_start`.